# How to make an animation with some previous slides

Tags: beamer, animations

I'd like to make an animation with some previous slide, how can I do that ?

`\transduration` does not affect `\againframe`, how to avoid this

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]

\item a
\item b
\item c

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\transduration<4->{.2}
\againframe<2->{bob}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\transduration` has no effect; perhaps a bug. So let's do it manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]

\item a
\item b
\item c

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\typeout{***** before \string\transduration:\the\pdfpageattr *****}
\transduration{.2} %doesn't work, why?
\typeout{***** after \string\transduration:\the\pdfpageattr *****}

% save current value of \pdfpageattr
\edef\pdfpageattrOrig{\the\pdfpageattr}
% append page duration to the page attributes (do it manually)
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{\the\pdfpageattr /Dur 0.2}%
}%
\x

\againframe<1->{bob} %auto-advancing frames

%reset page attributes to saved value
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{\pdfpageattrOrig}%
}%
\x

\againframe<1->{bob} %frames don't auto-advance any more

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could it loops only on selected frames ?

Comment: @Tarass Once set, the contents of the token register `\pdfpageattr` is *en vigueur* for the following pages of a PDF document. But one can reset it to a saved value. I am going to update the answer.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough : let say the frame as 3 slides, one show the 3 slides then one wants to loop only on two last. Your first hint makes this possible, the two last slides will pass automatically as they have a tranduration speed, but the I want to loop only  n this two slides (or any set I selected with `\againframe`) until I stop it.